# MS SQL: Get 3 characters in string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, character

How can I get specific char in string, between char space and 'IU' like this:

```
BEMFOLA 225IU/0,375ML
BEMFOLA 300IU/0,5ML
```

Result:

```
225
300
```

Comment: `SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length ) ` [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method with `charindex` and `substring`

```
declare @var varchar(16) = 'BEMFOLA 225IU/0,375ML'

select SUBSTRING(@var,charindex(' ',@var),charindex('IU',@var) - charindex(' ',@var))
```

If `IU` can be any two characters, then you can use:

```
select SUBSTRING(@var,charindex(' ',@var),charindex('/',@var) - charindex(' ',@var) - 2)
```

This takes the substring of your string from the first space, to two places before the slash.

Comment: You're welcome @Hans33 best wishes.